# Count Comparisons Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Good morning, I've having trouble with getting the following query to work, I started with

```
select A.equipment_id,
B.vendor_name,
    B.vendor_part_number,
    C.clli_code,
    (select count(*) from TABLE D where equipment_spec_id = 
B.equipment_spec_id) as Spec_PAs,
    (select count(*) from TABLE E where equipment_id = A.equipment_id) as 
Eqp_PAs,
    (select count(*) from TABLE F where equipment_spec_id = 
B.equipment_spec_id) as Spec_MPs,
    (select count(*) from TABLE G where equipment_id = A.equipment_id) as 
Eqp_MPs

from
    TABLE A 
    TABLE B,
    TABLE C
    where
A.equipment_spec_id = B.equipment_spec_id
and A.location_id = C.location_id
HAVING  Spec_PAs <> Eqp_PAs
order by 4,2,3
```

but I received an error ORA-00904: "EQP_MPS": invalid identifier

So I tried

```
SELECT * FROM (select A.equipment_id,
B.vendor_name,
    B.vendor_part_number,
    C.clli_code,
    (select count(*) from TABLE D where equipment_spec_id = 
B.equipment_spec_id) as Spec_PAs,
    (select count(*) from TABLE E where equipment_id = A.equipment_id) as 
Eqp_PAs,
    (select count(*) from TABLE F where equipment_spec_id = 
B.equipment_spec_id) as Spec_MPs,
    (select count(*) from TABLE G where equipment_id = A.equipment_id) as 
Eqp_MPs

from
    TABLE A 
    TABLE B,
    TABLE C)
    where
A.equipment_spec_id = B.equipment_spec_id
and A.location_id = C.location_id
HAVING  Spec_PAs <> Eqp_PAs
order by 4,2,3   

ERROR: ORA-00904: "C"."LOCATION_ID": invalid identifier
```

The answer is probably something simple. Any help is greatly apreciated

Comment: Some issues here; `TABLE` is a reserved word, you can not use it that way. `HAVING` requires a `GROUP BY`; missing commas; you are using an old deprecated join syntax, better switching to ANSI. If you would post some sample data and needed result, it would be easier to understand you need and help you.

Comment: TableC columns are not available outside the sub-query.

Comment: I just used TABLE in replacement of the actual table name, I'm not able to use the actual sample data or the specific table names due to confidentiality requirements. Essentially what I'm trying to do is filter the results to only show the differences between the data returned for Spec_PAs and Eqp_PAs, since they are column aliases I had to use a sub query, I was under the impression that I could use ORDER_BY or GROUP_BY but when I tried GROUP_BY I received the same error. Not sure what else I can add to further explain my issue

Comment: [mcve] is a good guide for that. Try to post some sample data and needed result that can describe your need. Even if these don't exactly match your tables and data, they can be useful to help people to suggest a way that you can adapt to your actual tables

Comment: I apologize if I'm not understanding, if the data being returned is simple count (numerical) data and all I'm trying to do is return the differences between two count results what else could I provide without using actual data?

Answer (score -1):

missing comma after TABLE A

Try Changing this

```
from
    TABLE A 
    TABLE B,
    TABLE C)
    where
```

To this

```
    from
    TABLE A, 
    TABLE B,
    TABLE C)
    where
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a type for the example, the actual query has the comma